# Changes to CSS on WP site not being recognized

Tags: css, wordpress, caching

So to start off, I'll say that I've disabled the CDN (AWS CloudFront), and all plugins, have deleted my cache and I'm still having problems with this.

I'm making a few changes to a rather "messy" WP site that I didn't build. Anytime I make changes to the CSS, they're not being recognized. If, using firebug, I look at what css file is being used for an element, instead of the regular style.css, I'm seeing a long string that includes a bunch of the enabled plugins and ends with pagespeed.cf.(long-string).css

After doing entering the string into a google search, I get a bunch of hits related to Google PageSpeed Insights, but I'm not sure how the site is interacting with that or causing the block to the original .css file.

Has anyone come across this before and if so, might you be able to explain to me what's going on and how I can go about bypassing this?

As always, thanks in advance for any answers or advice!

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache?

Comment: Sorry I thought you meant the server cache when you said you deleted cache. Do you get the same results in an incognito/private window?

Comment: Cheers Colin, yeah I emptied both. It looks the same with incognito, though when looking at the source in firebug - incognito, it says it's reading the actual style.css, not pagespeed.cf.(long-string).css etc.

Comment: Have you tried adding `define('WP_CACHE', false);` to your wp-config.php file?

Comment: Thanks Colin, I'll try that. Currently waiting on cpanel or ftp credentials.